# How to prevent cmake rebuilds in GitLab between pipeline stages

Tags: c++, cmake, gitlab-ci

I have a project that uses cmake ExternalProject to build my dependencies. This means my setup to build can be a little tedious of downloading my dependencies and then building them. The dependencies are all in house, with no prebuilt binaries.

In my GitLab pipeline I’d like to have independent stages for building, testing, and code analysis. The problem I run into is if I try to artifact my GitLab build directory between stages CMake is unhappy that the path changes as GitLab creates temporary directories for each stage. This means I end up doing a complete setup and build multiple times in my pipelines which makes running the pipeline take forever for each build.

Has anyone solved not having to do rebuilds between GitLab stages for CMake? Seems like the going answer is to just do the rebuild, I hope someone else has a better solution.

I am currently just rebuilding.

I stumbled upon cmake presets which gave me hope as I was able to update my top level CMakeCache file but it didn’t work for my ExternalProjects CMakeCache files.

Comment: can't you just make the build directory something/somewhere that doesn't change / get moved around?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: Where is code of your pipeline? Why you have new directory each stage?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your literal question "How to prevent cmake rebuilds in GitLab between pipeline stages": You could use the "artifacts", see a good description [here](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/12/10/basics-of-gitlab-ci-updated/) for example.

But I have to comment on

> I have a project that uses cmake ExternalProject to build my dependencies. This means my setup to build can be a little tedious of downloading my dependencies and then building them.

Man, you do it wrong, sorry. Look into building your dependencies into an image you use to build your code.